# Is it possible to create a temporary alias for a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, alias

I have a situation where the code I'm working with creates a temporary database table that contains a record store.

As the application has grown, the calculations required to build the temporary database table have gotten to the point where in some cases they are taking more than a few seconds to process.

As one potential vector for performance improvement, I am considering adding the ability to flag (or auto flag) those cases, and use a permanent table that gets updated when a record is changed instead.

My only issue is that the (PHP) function that creates the temporary table takes a `$tableName` parameter, which is used in the calling code once the temporary table is created. The `$tableName` is often generated in part based on IDs, so it can vary a lot.

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a temporary alias such that `SELECT * FROM MyCustomTable_1234` will return results directly from `PermanentTable_1234` for the duration of that connection?

The closest option I can come up with is to create a view for each `$tableName` that gets requested, but then I will potentially end up with a whole bunch of identical (but differently named) views on a busy server unless I go through and put in cleanup code every where it gets used, which is a lot of places.

Comment: Could you refactor so the function also returns the table name? If it creates the temporary table, it will return the name that was given. If it uses the permanent table, it returns its name, and the caller uses that instead.

Comment: The best I can think of is to make a temporary copy of the permanent table. Not as simple as creating an alias, but better than recalculating everything.

Comment: @Barmar - I could refactor the function, but I would still have to go through all the code and update it to work that way, which is what I'm hoping to avoid. Making a temporary copy of the permanent table is a possibility, but still not ideal for large tables.

Comment: @Barmar whoops, that'd be me missing a detail on the question. The temptable solution is the route I'd have gone, which you suggested.

Comment: I don't think your approach can be achieved.  Constructing (in PHP or a Stored Proc) SQL statements with a variable (`$tablename`) being substituted is quite viable.

Comment: If the question is "How do I automatically issue `DROP TABLE` when PHP finishes", there are a couple of ways (in PHP) to do that.

Comment: @Rick James - That is not the question. I want to keep the table always there so I don't have to rebuild it, but I want to know if I can access it by different names so I don't need to modify the code